# How can I get specific information about the serial (COM) port in Windows?

Tags: windows, delphi, bluetooth, serial-port

Since I have dozens of virtual serial (COM) ports installed and the half of them are Bluetooth devices, I'd like to know what port belong to what device and whether it's connecting directly or via Bluetooth.

So in particular I'm not interested in the trivial enumeration of all serial ports, which would only reveal a list of 'COM' + the corresponding number, but the real name of that device and probably its device ID (where information can be found about whether this is connecting via USB or Bluetooth.

While I could get these information via WMI, there are a plenty of problems related to this method. In particular it's bloody slow, but also it does only list connected devices (except for Bluetooth devices, that can potentially be connected and are shown regardless of a real connection)

I'd prefer a solution written in Delphi / Object Pascal, but any other language is also fine for me (the WMI access code was copied from C#).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use a programming language/API that can read the registry, check the subtree `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum`.

This has subkeys containing device type, device class, instance ID. Each Instance ID has a subkey `Device Parameters\PortName` that has the COM name.

For example, on my system

```
ACPI\PNP0501\1\Device Parameters\PortName = COM1
BTHENUM\{GUID}{ID}\Device Parameters\PortName = COM4
```

The keys in the ID Part have additional information, for example

```
ACPI\PNP0501\1\FriendlyName = Kommunikationsanschluss (COM1)  (german windows)
ACPI\PNP0501\1\Service = Serial
BTHENUM\{GUID}{ID}\Service = BTHMODEM
```

Use regedit to check for yourself which parts are interesting to you. But this should give you all information you need.

Comment: I had been crawling SO up and down in search of a way to get this info. Saw dozens of questions... and at least as many answers, and this is so far the only straightfoward one. Thank you very much, you helped me solve a problem!

Comment: I use 'hardware\devicemap\serialcomm' and in the key name there is a hint what kind of device it is, such as \Device\BthModem0 for a bluetooth device and \Device\USBSER000 for an USB device.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same exact thing in my com ports list (being reserved in device manager):

ACPI\PNP0501

and the only way i was able to see even this was using this nice tool:

**COM Name Arbiter Tool (V1.0.5)**

if you want to start using it, then the **1st thing** you should really do is to **select**:

"**Options -> Show device ID**" to get some actual usefulness out of the program in the first place.

i'm not even sure why is it not ticked in the first place, becase now i will never know what the 0501 device was that was reserving the com port the whole time, lol...

and i would also suggest **NOT** to click "Clear unused reservations", because it "cleared" 0 of them and now i dont have any "com port reserved" text in the device manager anymore -

so you can basically only click "Remove non-present devices" to fix your issue (although you should first check what device is reserving the port with the "show device id" option mentioned before...)